# Why TypeScript lets me add a string and a number? Can I prevent it?

Tags: typescript

The following code

```
let k = "1";
k += 1;
console.log(k);
```

compiles correctly using TypeScript, even in strict mode. I would have expected tsc to fail with some error like `Cannot add a string and an integer.`. Why does it build successfuly? Can I prevent this dangerous behavior?

Comment: The `+` operator between string and number is valid in TypeScript and JavaScript. Why do you want to prevent this?

Comment: Because I would have expected TypeScript to force explicit coercions. The code I've written will 99% of time be a programming error and I want TS to raise them at build time, as long as possible. I can't think of any strongly typed language where this is allowed and makes sense.

Comment: For what is worth, the opposite is illegal: if `k` was a `number`, TypeScript would error on `k += "1"`.

Comment: Relevant TypeScript GitHub Issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30239

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"It's valid because it's valid in JS" is a non-answer in the context of why a certain operation isn't a type error; see [What does "all legal JavaScript is legal TypeScript" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750390/what-does-all-legal-javascript-is-legal-typescript-mean)

In JavaScript, code like `alert("Your position in the queue is " + queuePos)` is idiomatic and common -- it is *not* commonly written as `"str" + num.toString()`.

TypeScript's position is that idiomatic JS should not cause type errors (when practical). This means that `string + number` is an allowed coercion.

The question of what `+=` should do is then a matter of choosing between two options:

- *consistency*: `x = x + y` should be identical to `x += y`
- *safety*: `x += y` is *not* commonly done between `string` and `number` operands, so should be an illegal coercion

Both choices are sensible and defensible; TypeScript happened to choose the first.

Comment: Many thanks. This is indeed way more convincing than the "All JS is valid TS" thing. I find `"str" + (5).toString()` more explicit than the idiomatic form (which I find dangerous), but this is very likely to come from my own background and sensibility.

Comment: Oh, and I just read the SO question you linked and it really puts all this and TS choices into perspective. 

Comment: So to summarize, by design TS allows `string` + `number` and will not throw an error during compilation? We just need to accept it? That's a little disappointing I would say.

Comment: Although `"str" + 3` may be idiomatic (to some people -- I never think it that way), it is not allowed in many other strong typed language -- C, C++, Java, Python etc. If I had wanted all the baggage of JavaScript I would not be using TS. I have already had a few instances of unintended use of string + number that is not reported

Answer (score 7):

You can prevent this sort of accident with the TypeScript-ESLint rule [restrict-plus-operands](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/restrict-plus-operands.md):

> When adding two variables, operands must both be of type number or of type string.
>
> Config examples:
>
> `"restrict-plus-operands": true`

If you enable that rule, the following code:

```
const x = 5;
const y = 'foo';
const z = x + y;
console.log(z);
```

will result in:

> ERROR: .ts - Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers, but found 5 + "foo". Consider using template literals.

The rule not only prevents use of `+` between strings and numbers, but it also prevents use of `+=` when the left-hand side type is different from the right-hand side type.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there is currently no way of preventing such a conversion, aside from building an abstraction of your own. Something like this (admittedly, not very elegant):

```
function safe_add(x: string, y: string): string { return x + y; }

let x = "1";
x = safe_add(z, 1); // Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

The usual policy of TypeScript's type checking, according to ["All legal JavaScript is legal TypeScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750390/1233251), is to prevent situations which are clearly wrong and never actually useful. For example, passing a string to `Math.max` is prevented. Unlike this example however, the `+` operator between a string and a number, despite not always desirable, is indeed a valid operation, and is employed too often in practice to be barred by the compiler. As `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`, and always resulting in a string when `x` is a string, the assignment itself is also valid. This is one of those cases that are most likely going to remain as OK by the compiler. Issue [#20131](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20131) aims to make a few more operations throw a warning, but this one in particular is not included.

As you might already understand, the opposite is successfully prevented, since a variable is not expected to change its type with the add-assignment operator.

```
let y = 1;
y += "1"; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

See also:

- [What does "all legal JavaScript is legal TypeScript" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750390/1233251)
- [TypeScript error on implicit type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47361859/1233251)

Comment: +1. I think the fact that the variable type doesn't change is indeed a major argument in favor of not disallowing this. Even though I tend to think it's a bit too permissive, it's not as bad as it seems, and the rest is a matter of taste which has nothing to do on SO :-) . Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @user8808265 Indeed, it mostly comes down to how the language has been designed. As an appreciator of static typing, I also prefer my code not to make surprising assumptions. For example, Rust (the language I'm currently more active on here) has very few implicit coercions.

Answer (score 1):

In short: because it is valid JS and Typescript as @Explosion Pills already pointed out.

The reason is `k += 1` is just syntactic sugar for `k = k + 1` which one would expect to be *11*.
So something like this also works:

```
let text = "hello ";
text += "world!"
console.log(text);
```

Which ends up being *hello world!*

Comment: Well, in your example, you concatenate a string with a string. The question was definitely not about the `+=` operator.

Comment: @user8808265 well typescript is just a superset of javascript , the syntax that you are using is valid in javascript too.

Comment: @Niladri `let i = 1; i = 1 + "";` is valid in JS and not in TS because it changes "i" type. So it's probably not the real reason.

Answer (score 1):

TSLint suggests to use template literals instead of coercion of string and number variables, 
eg: `'Hello ' + person.name` would become `` `Hello ${person.name}` ``