# Why can I create an index dynamically in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Why does the following code pass the Typescript compiler?

```js
type O = {
  name: string
  city: string
}

function returnString(s: string) {
  return s
}

let o1: O = {
  name: "Marc",
  city: "Paris",
  [returnString("random")]: "London",
}
```

Comment: looks like a compiler bug, maybe?  [microsoft/TypeScript#22427](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22427) seems like the exact issue but it was closed as "fixed" even though it sure doesn't seem fixed to me 

Comment: Okay I just opened [microsoft/TypeScript#36920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36920) and I'll come back to post info here if I get an answer as to what's happening.  Good luck

Comment: That's a good one ! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Why does this surprise you?

The code passes because, for one thing, it's valid plain-old JavaScript as of ES2015.

Even if it wasn't valid JavaScript, since this code can be translated to JavaScript that doesn't directly support computed key values, and it's a very nice, convenient thing to be able to do... why not support it?

As ES2015:

```
"use strict";
function returnString(s) {
    return s;
}
let o1 = {
    name: "Marc",
    city: "Paris",
    [returnString("random")]: "London",
};
```

Transpiled to ES5:

```
"use strict";
var _a;
function returnString(s) {
    return s;
}
var o1 = (_a = {
        name: "Marc",
        city: "Paris"
    },
    _a[returnString("random")] = "London",
    _a);
```

Comment: Because it seems inconsistent to me for the reason that I could not enter `random: "London",` instead.

Comment: This answer implies that valid JavaScript should not result in a TypeScript compiler warning, but [that's not the way it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52102877/2887218) (see also [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750390/what-does-all-legal-javascript-is-legal-typescript-mean))

Comment: In particular, this question is asking why adding a computed property does not trigger [excess property warnings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).  The answer cannot be "because it's valid ES2015".  It *could* be "because the TS maintainers decided that this is idiomatic JS and shouldn't be warned", but that would need a documentation link or github issue link or something to back it up.  Otherwise it's just conjecture/opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `: never` type. I believe this is a very advanced typescript concept which is usually used to [discriminate unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

This is not a complete answer but it could serve you like a hint to understand the problem, it loses the scope of the string return value.

```
type O = {
  name: string
  city: string
}

declare const neverValue: never;

// This will fail
// function returnStringS(s: string): 's' {
//     return 's';
// }

// This will work
function returnStringS(s: string): string {
  return 's';
}

// This will work
function returnStringS(s: string): string {
  return s;
}


let o1: O = {
  name: "Marc",
  city: "Paris",
  [returnStringS("random")]: "London",
}

let o2: O = {
  name: "Marc",
  city: "Paris",
  [returnString("random")]: "London",
}

const some2: O = {
  name: "Marc",
  city: "Paris",
  [neverValue]: "London"
}
```

At the Typescript documentation [TS never type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) is the key of this issue/concept.

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself). Even any isn’t assignable to never.

Comment: There's no `never` type here.  The question's `returnString()` returns `string`, not `never`.  It isn't *annotated* to return `string`, but the compiler infers it anyway.  So this answer doesn't seem relevant, unless I'm missing something.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: The point is that the `: never` type is the only type that can be used to extend a defined size interface or type, and since it is assignable to every type (as written in the documentation)  such as `: string` it could explain or at least serve as a hint why it accepts a `: string` but not a `: 's'` defined string.